# How to fix tableHeaderView and make it scrollable programatically in swift 3?

Tags: swift, tableview, nstableheaderview

I used `UITextView` for `tableHeaderView` but it moves. How can I fix `tablHeaderView`? And also when text is too much, it is off of the `tableHeaderView`. So I want to make it scrollable too. How do I make it do so? I couldn't find good recourses to make this happen. I appreciate your help!!

Comment: share some code please

Comment: The tableHeaderView is scrollable content. Because it's header of your tableView object. Use the section headers instead